# Tomcat class loading order when serving modules without publishing

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am using tomcat with eclipse.

According to tomcat's documentation:
**from the perspective of a web application, class or resource loading looks in the following repositories, in this order:**

- Bootstrap classes of your JVM System class loader classes (described 
  above)
- /WEB-INF/classes of your web application
- /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application
- Common class loader classes (described above)

So when loading a classes, tomcat will look up **WEB-INF/classes** before **WEB-INF/lib**.
And we can overwrite some class in jar files in WEB-INF/lib, tomcat will pick up the overwritten one.

But now if I changed the tomcat server options by checking "Serve modules with out publishing" 
, then overwritten classes will not be loaded any more.

Is there any solution to make that works again, but I still want tomcat to serve modules without publishing.

---

Edits:
I have found something may be useful, in this folder **f:\eclipse_projects\.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf**
there is a server.xml it contains such content:

```
<Resources className="org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.loader.WtpDirContext" 
    extraResourcePaths="" 
    virtualClasspath="F:\eclipse_projects\ALS7C3\bin"/>
<Loader className="org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.loader.WtpWebappLoader" 
    useSystemClassLoaderAsParent="false" 
    virtualClasspath="F:\eclipse_projects\ALS7C3\bin"/>
```

It seems that when running tomcat with option "Serve modules without publishing" checked, eclipse will use it's own loader.This loader is contained in a jar file which will be copied to **f:\eclipse_projects\.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\lib** when you start tomcat in eclipse.
Here is part of source code of **org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.loader.WtpDirContext**:

```
public Object lookup(String name) throws NamingException {
        if (name.startsWith("/WEB-INF/") && name.endsWith(".tld")) {
            String tldName = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            if (virtualMappings != null && virtualMappings.containsKey(tldName)) {
                return new FileResource(virtualMappings.get(tldName));
            }
        } else if (tagfileMappings != null && name.startsWith("/META-INF/tags")
                && (name.endsWith(".tag") || name.endsWith(".tagx"))) {
            // already loaded tag file
            return new FileResource(tagfileMappings.get(name));
        } 

        Object retSuper;
        NamingException superEx;
        try {
            retSuper = super.lookup(name);
            return retSuper;
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            retSuper = null;
            superEx = ex;
        }
        if (mappedResourcePaths != null) {
            // Perform lookup using the extra resource paths
            for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> mapping : mappedResourcePaths.entrySet()) {
                String path = mapping.getKey();
                List<String> dirList = mapping.getValue();
                if (name.equals(path)) {
                    for (String resourcesDir : dirList) {
                        File f = new File(resourcesDir);
                        if (f.exists() && f.canRead()) {
                            if (f.isFile()) {
                                return new FileResource(f);
                            }
                            else {
                                // TODO Handle directory
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                path += "/";
                if (name.startsWith(path)) {
                    String res = name.substring(path.length());
                    for (String resourcesDir : dirList) {
                        File f = new File (resourcesDir + "/" + res);
                        if (f.exists() && f.canRead()) {
                            if (f.isFile()) {
                                return new FileResource(f);
                            }
                            else {
                                // TODO Handle directory
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        throw superEx;
    }
```

it seems that if it will first handle jsp tag library then call **super.lookup**, if can't find in **super.lookup**, it will try to load resource in virtualClasspath, "F:\eclipse_projects\ALS7C3\bin" in my example, it's where eclipse output class files when serving modules without publishing.

So, I guess, I can get what I want if I can overwrite the **lookup** method of **org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.loader.WtpDirContext**, however this jar file is contained in **org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.jar**, both of them are signed.

I don't know how to overwrite such a jar file.

Any one can help ?

Comment: Why do you want to override your classes? Programs shouldn't depend on the behaviour of classloading. Implementations differ.

Comment: @Keerthi For convenience at development time,  we have some jar files that have no source code or documentation. For example, I want to change the log format to get rid of useless information when developing, but the log format is hard coded in some class in those jars.

Comment: You can control the logging levels based on the package.As per my knowledge,Class loader will not load a class with the same name and package structure again. i.e. override. The order in which the classes are loaded are important.Please let me know if i wrong

Comment: @Keerthi thanks for your help. I do not want to change logging levels but logging message format. For tomcat, as I know, it allows two classes with same name(include package declaration) exist in class path at same time.

Comment: +1 Upvoted your question, over my head.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do to use hot deploy with eclipse/tomcat :

1. Stop the tomcat
2. Open the tomcat configuration menu
3. Check "Serve modules without publishing" in the Server Options tab
4. Check "Never publish automatically" in the Publishing tab
5. Save the configuration
6. Start the tomcat in debug mode (This is very important)

Maybe try with a new tomcat if you changed the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to overwrite these classes is modifying `Servers\???-config\catalina.properties` in workspace project.

> common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar

The property `common.loader` is the classpath setting for Tomcat common ClassLoader.
Webtools plugin copy **org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.jar** to `${catalina.base}/lib`.
You can overwrite these classes and replace `${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar` with new path.